# Would Viking houses be warm enough to raise guinea pigs?

Tags: vikings

The title is pretty self explanatory.

I’m wondering if it is easy to raise guinea pigs in a subarctic environment inside a house. Theses houses would be as advanced as your typical Viking house. I’m guessing it would be possible, but I’m a little unsure.

Comment: The title should probably mention the guinea pigs, since otherwise you're just asking for a historical fact.

Comment: ? Guinea pigs *Cavia porcellus* are domesticated rodents originating in the *Andes*, think Peru and Bolivia. (The species does not exist in the wild.) They were grown on large scale for their meat; the conquistadors found them cute and brought them to Europe. Bolivia is not warmer than Sweden or Denmark. If the indigenous people of Peru and Bolivia were able to grow guinea pigs then most definitely Danes and Swedes could grow them too.

Comment: Viking/Subarctic- Iceland? Why would they "raise" guinea pigs?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Duh. Didn't you read AlexP's post? For food. Obviously.

Answer (score 5):

As guinea pigs are much more sensitive to excess heat (35°C and more often lead to hyperthermia and death) and to humidity than to  very low temperatures keeping them there should be possible in general. Keeping them inside and dry and don't forgett to keep the fireplace burning should do the trick.

Comment: Don't need a fire if you bring the cows inside during the winter. Cows are big and put out a lot of heat.